# How to compile mule application through command lne

Tags: mule

I want to separate the deployment portion and the compilation portion of a mule application. Does anyone know how to do this? To be specific, if I want a script that can compile my mule application, what do I need to do? **What are the libraries that will be required for this**?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `maven-mule-plugin` to have Maven build an application archive.

Here is a sample configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                <excludeMuleDependencies>true</excludeMuleDependencies>
                <inclusions>
                    <inclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-module-cache</artifactId>
                    </inclusion>
                </inclusions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Be sure to have this repository active at build time:

```
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
```

Also be sure to have:

```
<pluginGroup>org.mule.tools</pluginGroup>
```

in your `<pluginGroups>` (typically in `~/.m2/settings.xml`).

Comment: Can anyone elaborate further on achieving this through ant? I have already gone through the linke - http://blogs.mulesoft.org/building-mule-apps-with-ant/ but I am still confused. In an environment where, we do not have mule installed, how can we build the application. I mean is there a way by which we can copy specific mule libraries, put them in a place and then tell ant to pick these libraries and compile the application.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use Maven: Mule is built with Maven, its extensions are too, its tools are Maven-based, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the question posted also asking for the command to acutally compile and create the deployment via the command line. As long as the pom is setup correctly just type the following (as long as maven is installed)

```
mvn clean package
```

The archived package ready for deployment will be in the target directory.

Answer (score -1):

See... You don't need to get Mule installed....  Only you need to get Maven installed.....
After creating an application in your Mule ..... Add the above Plugin in the pom.xml file and it use the command mvn clean install in your command prompt ...... it will automatically build the application and deploy it to Mule standalone